# pass string from c# to unmanaged c# using managed c++ wrapper

Tags: c#, c++

I currently have a simple unmanaged C++ method which just displays a messageBox. I have created a managed c++ wrapper for this, which I then reference in my c# application.
I need to be able to pass strings and other variables from the c# into the unmanaged c++ and back again but I am having trouble with the conversion of the strings as my c++ knowledge is very basic.

My end goal is to be able to call complicated functions from our legacy unmanaged c++ libraries via my new c# app (not using DLLImport or COM) but I am trying to create a simple example before progressing.

Thanks in advance.
Rich

Comment: A decent question that would be much better with examples of what you have tried.

Comment: Can you include some code please?

Comment: System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(msg).ToPointer() looked the most promising but I've tried too many variations to list them all. Ideally I'd like to go from string in C# to LPCTSTR in C++ but due to my lack of C++ knowledge I'm not sure what will convert to what along the way. I'm guessing the conversion would need to happen in the Managed C++ in order to leave the Unmanaged C++ intact.

Comment: You have to pick a string type for your C++ app.  There is never a lack of choices.  Just don't pick LPCTSTR, that's from the previous century.  std::wstring is an obvious choice, well supported by marshal_as<>.

Comment: Thanks Hans. A combination of changing MessageBox to MessageBoxA and using the marshal_as<> method worked.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the unmanaged C++ method looks something like this:

```
namespace UnmanagedCpp
{
    class MessageBox
    {
    public:
        static void Show(LPCTSTR lpszMessage)
        {
            ::MessageBoxW(NULL, lpszMessage, L"Message", 0);
        }
    };
}
```

You could wrap it in something like this:

```
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

namespace ManagedCpp
{
    public ref class MessageBox
    {
    public:
        static void Show(String^ message)
        {
#if defined(UNICODE) || defined(_UNICODE)
            IntPtr intPtr = Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(message);
#else
            IntPtr intPtr = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(message);
#endif

            UnmanagedCpp::MessageBox::Show(static_cast<LPTSTR>(intPtr.ToPointer()));
            Marshal::FreeHGlobal(intPtr);
        }
    };
}
```

If you're planning on doing more extensive interop between C# and C++, I recommend COM as it doesn't require you to write any wrappers (which get really messy in more complicated scenarios), although of course it requires you to modify the existing C++ code.